# How do I strip a line comment of a line containing multiple strings and comment symbols

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to parse KConf files which contain single line comments which are introduced by the `#` character. Below you can find an example of such file.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/Kconfig

I am aware that the single line test string almost looks random though it should contain most if not all variants of nested hashes and strings and quotes in comments which do not introduce a string.

The regex engine that I use currently the one in Groovy which is based Java.

**Test string**

`Lorem "ipsum # \" dolor" sit amet, 'consectetur # \' adipiscing' elit. Maecenas 'suscipit #mollis' quam, non #bibendum 'elit # eleifend "in. Duis # convallis" luctus nunc, ac luctus lectus dapibus at.`

**Desired result**

`Lorem "ipsum # \" dolor" sit amet, 'consectetur # \' adipiscing' elit. Maecenas 'suscipit #mollis' quam, non`

**or** (with the leading space)

`#bibendum 'elit # eleifend "in. Duis # convallis" luctus nunc, ac luctus lectus dapibus at.`

Comment: Some explanation would be nice. Also, the language you're using the regex in. Oh and your attempts too.

Comment: `#bibendum 'elit # eleifend "in. Duis # convallis" luctus nunc, ac luctus lectus dapibus at.` seems to wrap, is there a natural newline in there?

Comment: Also, there is no apparent quoting rules from which to operate. Comments are stripped from strings at compile time, and this doesn't look like a source code string, it looks verbatim.

Comment: @sln it is a single line. the language i try to parse is KConfig and the quoting rules are either '\'"' or "\"'". I am added a quote in the comment to back up nonmatching quotes.

Comment: @Jerry I edited my question and added more info. I currently attempt to parse the KConfig files in Groovy (Java).

Comment: @166_MMX Any luck with the regex?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I've escaped your string so it can be stored as a variable using JavaScript (since you don't seem to indicate a language, I'll assume JS):

`var str = 'Lorem "ipsum # " dolor" sit amet, \'consectetur # \' adipiscing\' elit. Maecenas \'suscipit#mollis\' quam, non #bibendum \'elit # eleifend "in. Duis # convallis" luctus nunc, ac luctus lectus dapibus at.';`

To remove everything following a " " followed by a "#" which is *not* followed by a space:

```
str.replace(/ #[^ ].*/, '');
```

Lastly, your second desired result makes absolutely no sense.

All of this would of course be helped by a proper description.

Comment: Okay must give credit for find a solution for this exact test case :D Looks like I have to improve it. With an added space after `suscipit` your regex matches also inside a string :S http://regex101.com/r/fF8dA1

Comment: I assumed it was all supposed to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information, this regex might work.
It seems a little extra complex trying to distinquish embedded hashes from coments though.
Didn't have time to test it but cut'n pasted a few regex pieces.
Note that it should be used in *Multi-Line Mode*. And Everything is geared to a line parse.
I.e. nothing in the regex will span lines.

```
 #  (?-s)^(?:"[^"\\\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\n]*)*"|'[^'\\\n]*(?:\\.[^'\\\n]*)*'|[^#"'\s]+|(?<=[^\s#])\#+|[^\S\n]+(?!\#))*(?:[^\S\n]+|^)(\#.*)$
 #  "(?-s)^(?:\"[^\"\\\\\\n]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\\\n]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\\\n]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\\\n]*)*'|[^#\"'\\s]+|(?<=[^\\s#])\\#+|[^\\S\\n]+(?!\\#))*(?:[^\\S\\n]+|^)(\\#.*)$"

 (?-s)                   # Modifier, No dot all 
 ^                       # Beginning of line
 (?:
      "                       # Double quotes
      [^"\\\n]* 
      (?: \\ . [^"\\\n]* )*
      "
   |                        # or
      '                       # Single quotes
      [^'\\\n]* 
      (?: \\ . [^'\\\n]* )*
      '
   |                        # or
      [^#"'\s]+               # Not hash, quotes, whitespace
   |                        # or
      (?<= [^\s#] )           # Preceded by a character, but not hash or whitespace
      \#+                     # Embeded hashes
   |                        # or
      [^\S\n]+                # Whitespaces (non-newline)
      (?! \# )                # Not folowed by hash
 )*
 (?: [^\S\n]+ | ^ )      # Whitespaces  (non-newline) or BOL
 ( \# .* )               # (1), hash comment
 $                       # End of line
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw regex:

```
^((?:\\.|("|')(?:(?!\2|\\|[\r\n]).|\\.)*\2|[^#'"\r\n])+)#.+
```

Replace with `$1`:

Example:

```
String re = "^((?:\\\\.|(\"|')(?:(?!\\2|\\\\|[\\r\\n]).|\\\\.)*\\2|[^#'\"\\r\\n])+)#.+";
String line = "Lorem \"ipsum # \\\" dolor\" sit amet, 'consectetur # \\' adipiscing' elit. Maecenas 'suscipit #mollis' quam, non #bibendum 'elit # eleifend \"in. Duis # convallis\" luctus nunc, ac luctus lectus dapibus at.";
String uncommented = line.replaceAll(re, "$1");

//=> Lorem "ipsum # \" dolor" sit amet, 'consectetur # \' adipiscing' elit. Maecenas 'suscipit #mollis' quam, non
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gA6gU2)

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/gVF3uD)

Breakdown:

```
^                         # Beginning of line
  (                       # Beginning of 1st capture group
    (?:                   # Non-capture group 1
      \\.                 # Match an escaped character
    |
      ("|')               # Or, a quote (and capture it in 2nd capture group),
      (?:                 # Non-capture group 2
        (?!\2|\\|[\r\n]). # Followed by any character except relevant quote, \ or newline
      |
        \\.               # Or an escaped character
      )*                  # Close of non-capture group 2 and repeat as many times
      \2                  # Close the quoted part
    |
      [^#'"\r\n]          # Any non-hash, single/double quote, newline characters
    )+                    # Close of non-capture group 1 and repeat as many times
  )                       # Close capture group 1
  #.+                     # Match comments
```